# how to return arrays that foreach doesn't catch

Tags: php, arrays

i have problem with foreach loop, i have one variable with multiple arrays like those two on the bottom and i need to get arrays from [sub] level up... i use

```
foreach ($global['sub'] as $sub) {
    $global['sub'] = $sub;
    $global['child_id'] = $sub['id'];
    $global['child_name'] = $sub['name'];
    $global['child_url'] = $pr. $sub['url'];
}
```

but it works only for arrays that have arrays in **[sub]** but doesn't return second array where **[sub]** is empty
I try to get all arrays i $global variable those that have sub arrays in **[sub]** and those that doesn't have as well...

```
Array
(
    [Segment_id] => ......
    [Segment] => ......
    [Segment_url] => ......
    [Categories_id] => ......
    [Categories] => ......
    [Categories_url] => ......
    [sub_Categories_id] => ......
    [sub_Categories] => ......
    [sub_Categories_url] => ......
    [categoryId] => ......
    [categoryName] => ......
    [product_count] => ......
    [sub] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => ......
                    [name] => ......
                    [anchor] => 
                    [url] => ......
                    [description] => 
                    [productCount] => ......
                    [products] => ......
                        (
                            [0] =>
                            [1] =>
                            [2] =>
                            [3] =>
                            [4] =>
                            [5] =>
                        )

                )
```

and

```
Array
(
    [Segment_id] => ......
    [Segment] => ......
    [Segment_url] => ......
    [Categories_id] => ......
    [Categories] => ......
    [Categories_url] => ......
    [sub_Categories_id] => ......
    [sub_Categories] => ......
    [sub_Categories_url] => ......
    [categoryId] => 1394
    [categoryName] => ......
    [product_count] => ......
    [sub] => Array
        (
        )
```

i need to get

```
Array
(
    [Segment_id] => .....
    [Segment] => .......
    [Segment_url] => .......
    [Categories_id] => .....
    [Categories] => .....
    [Categories_url] => ......
    [sub_Categories_id] => ....
    [sub_Categories] => .....
    [sub_Categories_url] => ......
    [categoryId] => 397
    [categoryName] => ......
    [product_count] => ......
    [subid] => .....
    [sub_name] => ......
    [sub_url] => ......
    [description] => 
    [sub_productCount] => ......
```

second one that doesn't have anything in [sub] might be as is now...

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the `['sub']` sub array, and replace it with the 3 new variables you mention in the loop. Its really not clear what you are asking or trying to do, so could you try and enter the description again please

Comment: what you're saying isn't clear.

Comment: Hi, yes exactly i want to remove sub array and get only few keys to main array

Answer (score 0):

First check the existance of the `sub` sub array, if it exists process it and then remove it, otherwise do nothing or set the new fields to a default calue, or maybe `''` nothing

```
$pr = 'something';      // was not mentioned in your code

if ( isset($global['sub']) ) {
    
    $global['child_id']     = $global['sub']['id'];
    $global['child_name']   = $global['sub']['name'];
    $global['child_url']    = $pr . $global['sub']['url'];
    
    // remove the 'sub` sub array
    unset( $global['sub'] );
} else {
    // there is no `sub` sub array so create with some default values
    // or if you dont want anything in this case, remove the ELSE
    $global['child_id']     = 'default value';
    $global['child_name']   = 'default value';
    $global['child_url']    = 'default value';
}
```